# Php can't find hash function

Tags: php, apache-2.4, php5, php.ini

I'm using apache with php on amazon linux. I've updated php from 5.3 to 5.5 and apache from 2.2 to 2.4. Now calling

```
echo hash('sha256','wtf');
```

is behaving in a strange way. It works for a while and then starts working only 50% of the time. Apache error log is filled with 'Call to undefined function hash'.

There's no more code around this, I created a separate file with only that function used and half the time I see the hash and other half is http 500.

What could be causing this?
How can a module just disappear? I don't see extension=hash.so in any of the ini files but then again it works at the start. Restarting apache helps but I'd like to figure out what's going on. What might be a sane place to start searching from?

Comment: It turned out to be partially a code problem. Somehow using a function in one of the modules was making another function unavailable for that particular apache process. Still not sure about the cause but at least found a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying disabling any opcode cachers like opcache, APC, etc. if you have any enabled.

Also, see if there is anything in your php.ini for zend_extension and try disabling that.

Of course some code could rely on the above functionality so disable with caution.